# Get JSONArray from JSONObject

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have this json

```
{"results":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2} ]
```

And I want to have a String json just with the array

```
 [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2} ]
```

So far using JSON class from utils, I manage to get the JSONObject, but once that I have the JSONObject does not expose any method to get the JSONArray

```
   val parsed = JSON.parseRaw(source).get
   val results = parsed.getJSONArray("key") <-- This is what I was expecting.
```

Any idea how to get the JSONArray and put it back as String.

Any other library it´s a welcome.

Regards

Comment: Use `play-json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Play Json

To add the dependency to the `build.sbt`. Add the following line to the library dependencies.

```
libraryDependencies += ("com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.5.4")
```

Parse and retrieve array using key `results`

```
Json.parse("""{"results":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2}]}""") \ "results"
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> Json.parse("""{"results":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2}]}""") \ "results"
res27: play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult = JsDefined([{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2}])
```

**Scala REPL**

If you want to get the `JsArray` directly then use `as[JsArray]`

```
scala> (Json.parse("""{"results":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2}]}""") \ "results").as[JsArray]
res26: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2}]
```